# Dependency Injection and IoC practices in a inherently tight coupling design

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What's the best practice when dealing with a situation like the following (**simplified symbolic analogous case, not asking for a particular implementation solution)**:

Imagine I want to create a custom class that represents my physical Calendar at my office desktop. It can be translated in Java as a  GregorianCalendar(myCustomZone).

So, I create a class such as:

```
 class MyOfficeCalendar extends GregorianCalendar{
   public MyOfficeCalendar(){
        super(new SimpleTimeZone(...));
   }
 }
```

In these cases, code reviewers would say that instantiation in the constructor is a bad idea. But if I inject the SimpleTimeZone dependency into the constructor this seems to me like error prone,
since my dependency only should be instantiated in a desired way. I want the control at that scope, not exposing the possibility of erroneous injection. I mean, that certain instantiation is part of my caller class behaviour or paradigm. The definition of MyOfficeCalendar is precisely a GregorianCalendar working with this particular custom TimeZone instance.

So what is the best design usually in those cases?

- Force MyCalendar to be flexible enough for other non-intended uses which can make it incoherent and rely on a correct IoC container xml or a shared dev-user misconception since I am not forcing anything
- Instantiate in the constructor the absolute desired dependence
- Manage the Whole thing without my convenient OOP class (I like to
  adhere to the SingleResponsabilityPrinciple as much as I can)
- Change the whole architecture ?

Comment: Apart from the "why do you want to extend GregorialCalendar?", why do "code reviewers would say that instantiation in the constructor is a bad idea"?

Comment: What methods do you want to override from Calendar anyway? Also, are you aware that this API is now obsoleted by JSR 310? But anyway... Composition?

Comment: It's just a placeholder to simplify the idea of what I am asking. I will bold the part where I state it.

Comment: @Tunaki presumably because unless you're instantiating a data class that is used entirely internally (which is rarely the case), it's hard to test things that have dependencies `new`ed up in the constructor, instead of injected.

Comment: @fge Ok, I understand that, it was only an example to simplify it, but if you do composition how do you pass the instance? I am in the same trouble, I don't want anybody be free to choose any GregorianCalendar instantiation. The way it's instantiated is the whole purpose of my Custom Calendar? Why I want a custom object if it does not allow me to forget about fthe details that make it custom?

Comment: @fge (Or are you implying I should code-duplicate all GregorianCalendar functionality under a new extended Calendar interface?)

Comment: How do you pass the instance? Static factory method. And make your particular class's constructor non accessible publicly.

Comment: Ok, I see. But still I have mixed feelings about letting other class creating an instance that is the essence of behavior my own class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a builder to encapsulate the construction behavior. E.g.

```
public class MyOfficeCalendar extends GregorianCalendar{

    public static class Builder {

        private Integer rawOffset;


        public void setRawOffset(int rawOffset) {
            this.rawOffset = rawOffset;
        }

        public MyOfficeCalendar build(){
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

            int effectiveRawOffset = tz.getRawOffset();
            if(rawOffset != null){
                effectiveRawOffset = rawOffset;
            }
            SimpleTimeZone simpleTimeZone = new SimpleTimeZone(effectiveRawOffset, tz.getID());
            return new MyOfficeCalendar(simpleTimeZone);
        }
    }

   private MyOfficeCalendar(SimpleTimeZone simpleTimeZone){
        super(simpleTimeZone);
   }
 }
```

Client code can only set a few `SimpleTimeZone` properties. How much it can set depends on your builder implementation.

The builder can be used as a factory bean in IoC Frameworks.

Comment: That's a really elegant approach, thanks! Hope is enough for picky testers:)